# How to check console.log output in chrome? Need to debug a .js file that uses XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

Here is my utube.js (copy of a tutorial):

```
let getXMLFile = function(path, callback) {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("GET", path);
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200)
          {
            callback(request.responseXML);
          }
   };
   request.send();
};

getXMLFile("https://cors.io/?http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByCodeXML_WithNumMins?StationCode='+Stationcode+'&NumMins=90&format=xml", function(xml) {
  console.log(xml);
});
```

How can I check that this is gets the XML data I need? The content creator states 'you need to place it on a server or local host...' I tried placing the .js itself on my server and this simply opens it in a text format when I access it from my browser. Running the .js directly gives me a compile error (line 2, char 5, ';' expected).

The creator can debug from the chrome console (console displayed error in red, when fixed he could read the actual XML data in the console output). How do I get to this step?:
[image]

I suspect I need to place the .js in a html doc, place that on my server and then access it from my browser? Not sure where the console comes into play however.

Thanks for any help. This is my first time seriously using JS or attempting to use the console please try keep it simple!

Comment: Create a HTML file and inside wrap the script between `<script>` and `</script>` tags

Comment: So assuming I do that and drop it onto my server, access the html file from my browser: I've nothing actually displaying the log output on the html page. If I access the console now should it show log output?